# How to implement the action bar for Android version 4.0?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I implemented an app that works from 2.1 and on. But my app has the menu functionality to exit from the app. I installed the app in an Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS, version 4.0) device and it's working fine. But ICS doesn't have menu buttons - instead of this it has the action bar. I am new to this concept. I want to integrate this into my app. I tried but I am not succeeding.

For this I follow these steps:

1. `android:targetSdkVersion="11"` in the Android manifest.
2. `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` --> add to menu.xml (which is in the menu folder) but I get the following error:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'

Comment: Try [this](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) one. Also this [Developer's blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with a working [Options Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) implementation.  Test it on a 1.x or 2.x emulator to make sure it works.  Then set your `targetSdkVersion` to >=11 (if it isn't already) and verify the menu appears in the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) on >= 3.0.  *Only devices or emulators running Android 3.0 or above will draw an Action Bar. Older versions still use the Options menu.*  Once the menu appears in the ActionBar, you can start adding the `showAsAction` attribute to individual items in the menu XML.

To set `targetSdkVersion`:

Open up your Project properties, select Android, and select an Android SDK to link your project against.  For both the Project properties and your [Android Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Manifest) `targetSdkVersion`, I recommend using the newest SDK available.

[image: Screen shot illustrating setting targetSdkVersion]

`minSdkVersion` defines the lowest version of Android the app will run on.  `targetSdkVersion` defines the highest version of Android the app knows about when built -- which classes and methods are available, what constants are defined, etc.  It may run on newer versions, but it won't know about any features added after `targetSdkVersion`.

More information about [API Level](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).

If you want an ActionBar to display on Android <3.0, make a project based on [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or the [Action Bar Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) sample from the SDK.  But don't try this until you are comfortable with your ActionBar in >= 3.0.

Comment: Added screen shot and more detailed explanation

Comment: k thanks i will try and get back to you.(because my system don't have the 4.0.3 so i need to install this)

Comment: You don't need to do that. Just set both the manifest targetSdkLevel and your project properties to the newest version you have installed right now and you should be fine.  As long as they're >= 11.

Comment: is any other changes required for showing action bar? How to open the action bar.

Comment: The ActionBar displays automatically unless you hide it, on devices that have it.

Comment: i have HTC 1V(ICS). I set the theme android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". is any code is required for action bar.like ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: The NoTitleBar theme will suppress the ActionBar appearing.

Answer (score 0):

you may find a good Example code over [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#menu_tutorial).